# Unterschied zwischen "eigentlich" und "tatsächlich"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Könnte jemand mich erleuchten, was der Unterschied zwischen *tatsächlich* und *eigentlich* ist? Ich verstehe, dass beide als `actually` ins Englische übersetzt werden, aber was ist der genaue Unterschied dazwischen?

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich eine gute Frage. Eigentlich liegt der Unterschied, wie so oft, in der Bedeutung.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Abstrakte Frage. Über folgende Wörter könnte man sich unterhalten:

- *[eigentlich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigentlich)*
- *[wirklich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wirklich)*
- *[tatsächlich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tatsaechlich)*
- *[actual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actual#English)*
- *[real](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/real#English)*

Ich versuche mal Beispiele für die Verwendung unterschiedlicher Wörter im Deutschen zu geben, bei denen im Englischen überall mit *actual* gearbeitet wird:

Sagen wir, C. wird von seinem Freund H. gefragt, ob er ins Kino will:

> C: *Actually*, I don’t want to go.
>
> C: *Ehrlich gesagt* will ich nicht mitkommen.

Als H. einer Freundin I. erzählt, C. habe keine Lust, reagiert diese ungläubig:

> I: Did he *actually* say that?
>
> I: Hat er das *tatsächlich* so gesagt?

Daraufhin muss C. zugeben, dass er paraphrasiert hat:

> H: Well, these weren’t his *actual* words.
>
> H: Naja, das waren nicht seine *eigentlichen* Worte.

Und man fragt sich jetzt:

> What is *actually* the point of this story? What is *actually* the difference?
>
> Was ist *eigentlich* der Sinn dieser Geschichte? Was ist jetzt *eigentlich* der Unterschied?

---

Etwas Eigentliches ist auch immer etwas Tatsächliches, Wirkliches oder Wahres. Aber eigentlich zu sein, ist viel spezifischer.

Ich jedenfalls habe den Eindruck, dass lediglich diejenigen wirklichen Dinge *eigentlich* sind, die auch fehlleiten können: Die *eigentliche* Telephonnummer (nicht die falsche), die *eigentliche* Bedeutung (nicht die umgangssprachliche), die *eigentliche* Intention (nicht der Vorwand), die *eigentliche* Aussage (nicht die heruntergekochte Variante), das *eigentliche* Gesicht (nicht die Maske). Man beachte dabei die Wurzeln des Wortes im Worte *[eigen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigen)*.

In diesem Sinne bedeutet *eigentlich* sowas wie *wirklich* oder *tatsächlich* , aber ganz explizit *nicht fehlleitend* (meistens dann im Vergleich zu einem fehlleitendem Ding).

Meistens kann man dann statt *eigentlich* auch getrost *tatsächlich* schreiben, allerdings mit einem gewissen Bedeutungsverlust, der aber durch Kontext kompensiert werden kann. Statt *tatsächlich* hingegen *eigentlich* zu schreiben, kann manchmal schiefgehen:

> Er hat <s>eigentlich</s> tatsächlich den Kanzler beleidigt!

Comment: Also, das ist jetzt keine genaue Untersuchung, sollte man dazu sagen, sondern nur eine grobe Beschreibung des Wortgebrauchs, wie ich ihn gewohnt bin.

Comment: Ist gut geworden! Ich würde vielleicht noch hinzufügen, daß "eigentlich" besonders dann geeignet ist, wenn die in Frage stehende Tatsache den Annahmen zuwiderläuft: `Du ißt doch gern Gänsebraten?`-- `Nun ja, eigentlich bin ich Vegetarier und esse niemals Gänsebraten.` - Das ist eine Art, jemandem mitzuteilen, daß er sich irrt, daß man ihn mit dieser Mitteilung aber nicht verletzen möchte. Vgl. `Spinnst du? Ich esse doch keine Vogelleichen!`

Answer (score 3):

Man muss unterscheiden zwischen einer Verwendung als Adjektiv und einer als Adverb.

**Adjektiv**

Beide Wörter bedeuten *actual*, wobei *eigentlich* auf den Kern einer Sache zielt, während *tatsächlich* einen Unterschied zu einem "Dummy" ausdrückt.

> Das eigentliche Problem … – the actual/core/essential problem
>
> Der tatsächliche Preis … – the actual price (after tax and fees)

**Adverb**

*Tatsächlich* ist ein bisschen wie ein mitteldoll überraschtes *really*.

> Das hat tatsächlich geklappt.
>
> (Wow), that actually worked.

*eigentlich* tut drei Sachen. Zum einen kann es den Kern einer Sache ausdrücken.

> Eigentlich hab ich keinen Hunger.
>
> Actually (to be honest/as a matter of fact) I am not hungry.

Hier könnte man auch *tatsächlich* nehmen, jedoch ist dann der Kontrast stärker. Es klingt dann ein bisschen mehr wie eine super Enthüllung … tadah …

*Eigentlich* kann aber auch die auf es folgende Aussage in Zweifel ziehen.

> Eigentlich ja …
>
> Eigentlich nicht …

impliziert, dass ein *aber* folgt(folgen könnte), das das Gegenteil behauptet.

> Eigentlich hab ich keine Zeit …

Hier könnte man weiter betteln, denn es klingt ein bisschen wie

> Well, I don't really have time … (but if it is really REALLY important then I'll do it)

Die dritte Funktion ist ein *by the way*. Das funktioniert nur in Fragen, da aber sehr gut

> Hast du eigentlich Maria mal wieder gesehen?
>
> Have you seen Maria lately by the way?

Die meisten Deutschlerner verwenden *eigentlich* falsch, denn sie nehmen es vorwiegend in Funktion von *actually* im Sinne von … naja … *actually*

> Eigentlich mag ich Berlin.
>
> I actually like Berlin.

Das ist FALSCH. Das *eigentlich* impliziert ein *aber* hier. Die Leute denken, gleich kommen die negativen Aspekte zur Sprache. *Tatsächlich* funktioniert genauso wenig, denn es klingt zu überrascht/überraschend. Wie also würde man es übersetzen? Meiner Meinung nach gar nicht. Alle deutschen Übersetzungen von so einem *actually* fügen etwas in einer Stärke hinzu, die im Original nicht vorhanden ist. Wenn dein Gesprächspartner Berlin nicht mag, du aber schon, dann würde ich Folgendes vorschlagen:

> "I was in Berlin and it sucked balls"
>   "I actually like it"
>
> "Ich war in Berlin und die Stadt ist einfach nur scheiße."
>   "Also, ICH (Betonung) mag es."

Comment: Man kann „Eigentlich mag ich Berlin.“ schon so sagen, so im Tonfall: „Ach, eigentlich finde ich das ganz nett!“, vielleicht sollte man da „eigentlich“ nicht unbedingt an die erste Position im Satz stellen. Ich persönlich finde Berlin eigentlich auch nicht so schlimm.

Comment: Ja, aber "actually" is viel viel stärker. So ein bisschen wie "Wow, who would have thought."

Comment: "Wie's aussieht mag ich Berlin."